# Is there a way to retrieve lost code if it is still functional on my simulator?

Tags: swift, xcode, github, ios-simulator, git-pull

While using GitHub Desktop, I pulled some code and I lost all the edits I made to the master that I had cloned.  The code that I want to retrieve is still working on the simulator as a separate app under the same name, but I can't find any sort of version editor in XCode.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is committed then you may use

```
 git reflog
 git reset --hard (commit id here)
```

If your commit is deleted then you may use

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

Enjoy :)